# Multi-stage High Side MOSFET driver

Tags: voltage, mosfet

I have a system that has at most 10 20V batteries and each battery can push out 10A.  At each battery I have a SPST relay disconnecting each positive terminal in the ckt.  The SPST is driven by a 5V micro controller and a transistor.  I am trying to replace a N.O. Relay with a N-chan MOSFET.  This is what I currently have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvhb66.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what I thought I can do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6voo1.png)</sup>

Can anyone confirm that I am approaching this correctly? What would be other's suggestion in replacing these relays?

Comment: You need to sit down and do the Vgs calculations.

Comment: Yikes, This looks like a car wreck extravaganza. The common grounds of the various drivers are going to conflict. Draw in some ground points in your schematic, and you will see what I am pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, I don't for a moment believe that you've drawn your circuit correctly. After all, as long as even one relay is open, no current can flow.

However, let's pretend that what you've asked for is what you want. Then you can replace your relays with MOSFETs, with the gate drive transformer-isolated. The circuit would look something like this for each MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ito9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you still have a relay, but it is a very low power unit. Likewise, the transformer is a tiny little audio transformer. You need a source of AC, but you can use a single oscillator to drive all the channels; about 1 KHz should do you. The output of the transformers should be about 5 or 6 volts RMS.  R and C are determined by how fast you need the MOSFET to turn on and off.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close in your design. Not sure why you want to open circuit the entire battery series connection.  However, relay looks like best way to do this. Relays have low loss, isolated design, and easy to control.

However, if you need a way to do this electronically, you can do it with transistors. This is NOT A complete design, rather a guide to help you avoid the problems associated with your design concept : 
[image]
By using Opto-coupler, you avoid the problem of ground conflict.